# setInterval - javascript reset

Tags: javascript, setinterval, reset

I am using setInterval in a loop.  Once the condition has been met (aa=bb) and interval cleared, is it possible to reset interval?

```
var interval = setInterval(function() 
{                                       
   if( aa == bb) 
   {
     clearInterval(interval);                   
   }
} , 10000);
```

Comment: Could you please show a bit more of your code? What do you mean "in a loop"? Calling `setInterval` from within a loop creates multiple intervals that run simultaneously (and 95% of the time when I've seen this done it was due to a misunderstanding about how it works). What do you mean by "reset interval"?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the code a function like this, you can call it anytime to start it over.

```
function startInterval() {
   var interval = setInterval(function() {                                       
       if( aa == bb) {
         clearInterval(interval);                   
       }
    }, 10000);
}

startInterval();
```

Comment: aa and bb were in local scope. can I pass them in?

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge - You can define startInterval in that same scope and it will automatically have access to `aa` and `bb`.  If you pass them in, then they may end up separate copies that won't change when you expect them to.

Comment: thanks, I did that, but my code seems to be blasting through the startInterval function. can there be compatibility with jQuery?

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge - you'd have to show us more of your code for us to know why it isn't working properly.  The startInterval() function will execute and finish immediately.  It just starts the interval timer which proceeds on it's own.